# Where is the G key in VIM Adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

I just finished the:

```
  if ( practice ) { 
    perfect;
  }
```

puzzle and it mentions an alternate solution using the G key, which I don't have yet.  Where do I find it?

Answer (score 3):

Found it in the house above the Cheshire Cat islands!

Comment: Yup!  Don't forget you passed a house that was locked.  I was looking for quite some time.

Comment: where is that? maybe screen shot?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the beginning of the level where you can only traverse things with f's. There is a door there.

[image]